# Comment reflower for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, comments

Is there a built-in command or tool that can reflow C# comments in Visual Studio?

Sometimes, a section of code requires several lines of comments, and after extensive editing you have to manually insert the line breaks in the appropriately places so that it does not flow past the right edge of your editor window. I'd like to be able to do this with a single key command.

After many years of using Visual Studio I still miss the ability to M-q (c-fill-paragraph) in emacs.

Edit: The Agent Smith plugin does not reflow comments in the method body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ReSharper, there is the free [Agent Smith](https://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/) plugin that can reflow comments.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out. Agent Smith is able to reflow the XML comments (the '///' comments preceding a member) but not comments inside a member. I think this will be fixed this at some time.

Comment: The link to the Agent Smith NuGet package is at https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/AgentSmith/.

Answer (score 17):

Back when I was a Visual C++ Developer I wrote a fairly configurable comment formatting tool called Comment Reflower. I have since changed platforms and so stopped doing ports, but thankfully Christoph Nahr has kept it alive at http://www.kynosarges.de/CommentReflower.html

Comment: I have been using Comment Reflower for years, and I absolutely love it. It has near perfect justification for comments. I've just added instructions to this page to get it working in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: FYI, for convenience I'm hosting a [fork at GitHub](https://github.com/sschuberth/CommentReflower) incl. Christoph Nahr's changes.

Answer (score 12):

If you want near perfect comment justification with a single keystroke, use [Comment Reflower](http://www.kynosarges.org/CommentReflower.html).

Works with `VS2012`, `VS2013` and `VS2015`.

#### VS2012: To install/upgrade Comment Reflower for Visual Studio 2012

*Update 2015-08-31:There is now a [Comment Reflower extension](https://github.com/kmunson/CommentReflowerVSIX/) available in the extension gallery that easily installs directly from `Tools > Extensions and Updates` in VS2012, VS2013 and VS2015*.

1. Download "Comment Reflower" from http://www.kynosarges.de/CommentReflower.html, unzip into the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio Comment Reflower`.
2. Update file `CommentReflower.Addin` so that `Version` increments from `10.0` to `11.0` (this upgrades it from VS2010 to VS2012). NOTE: There are *two* spots in this .xml file where you have to update this version.
3. In VS2012, select `Tools..Options..AddIn Security` and add the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio Comment Reflower`.
4. Restart VS2012.
5. Now there is new menu items: `Tools..Reflow Comment at Cursor` and `Tools..Comment Reflower Settings`.

#### VS2013: To install/upgrade Comment Reflower for Visual Studio 2013

*Update 2015-08-31:There is now a Comment Reflower extension available in the extension gallery that easily installs directly from `Tools > Extensions and Updates` in VS2012, VS2013 and VS2015*.

Repeat instructions above, and change the version in step 2 from `11.0` to `12.0`.

#### VS2015: To install/upgrade Comment Reflower for Visual Studio 2015

There is now a [Comment Reflower extension](https://github.com/kmunson/CommentReflowerVSIX/) available in the extension gallery that easily installs directly from `Tools > Extensions and Updates` in VS2012, VS2013 and VS2015.

Thanks to @Martin Liversage for pointing this out.

#### To add a shortcut key that justifies the current comment your cursor is on

1. Go to `Tools..Options..Keyboard`, type `reflow` in `Show commands containing`, select `CommentReflower.Connect.ReflowPoint`, type a key combination (e.g. `Ctrl-J`) in the box `Press shortcut keys`, then hit `Assign`.
2. Now, if you position your cursor on a comment, and press said key combination (`Ctrl-J`), it will automatically (and beautifully) justify the comment for you. You should see the bound key appear in the `Tools` menu:

[image]

#### Update margin width

Go into `Tools..Comment Reflower Settings` and change the `Wrap Width` from the default of 80 to something wider, such as `140`, and the "Minimum Block Width" to `10` (do `*not*` set it to anything smaller!):

[image]

Comment: This description also applies to Visual Studio 2013 except the version in item 2 should be changed to __12.0__.

Comment: I just tried this and everything except hitting CTRL + J works. Any idea why not?

Comment: @Jon Cage I think you have to hit "Assign" (step 2 in the section on adding a shortcut key, above). Hitting "ok" without hitting "Assign" won't actually bind the key. In addition, sometimes the justification won't appear to do anything if its already justified, so to test if it works, unjustify it by creating a huge line then hit "Reflow Comment At Cursor" again.

Comment: There is now a [Comment Reflower](https://github.com/kmunson/CommentReflowerVSIX/) extension available in the extension gallery that easily installs directly from **Tools** > **Extensions and Updates** in VS2012, VS2013 and VS2015.

Comment: Brilliant, absolutely brilliant! I have updated the answer to reflect this comment.

Comment: Do you have any tips for upgrading from the addin to the extension? I'm concerned about losing my custom rules.

Comment: It's probably easier to just take a series of screenshots with a utility such as http://getgreenshot.org/, then upgrade, and you can re-enter the settings manually if they disappear. Out of interest, what are your settings? I'm curious!

Comment: OK, fair enough. Just figured I'd check if anyone had any experience of it. Maybe I'll see if I can find out where the extension stores the xml (assuming it still uses one). The settings aren't anything exciting. I've defined some extra blocks e.g. for xml comments. I think I've also defined some custom bullet styles. Most of it is so that I can conform to our coding standard with regards to function comment blocks in C. I can send you more info if it's useful?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `//` or `///`-style comments [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/documentation/#formatting) has worked great for me. It is free and open source, and I can use it in both C++ and C#.