# Method to justify text within comments in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there an automated method to justify comments in Visual Studio?

Example:

```
/// This is a comment
/// that needs to be justified so every line is roughly 120 chars long.
/// Yes I could do it manually
/// but if I'm faced with a 60-line comment I would rather kiss my own toe.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837717/comment-reflower-for-visual-studio/3225417#3225417

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the freely available [CommentReflower](http://www.kynosarges.de/CommentReflower.html) add-in.

Answer (score 0):

See [Comment reflower for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837717/comment-reflower-for-visual-studio/).

I have been using this for years, and it works brilliantly.